# App Crashes because of "ServiceConnectionLeaked"

Tags: android, crash

I added a few buttons to my applications and ran it again and it crashed upon finishing one run. I'm not sure what brought it about but this is the following error in debug mode:

```
06-20 23:21:59.656    2323-2323/com.android.email E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2ded40e8 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2ded40e8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1774)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
        at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
        at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
        at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
        at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
        at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
        at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

So I clicked the first LoadedApk (which I did not modify)
and this is the code I saw

```
        ServiceDispatcher(ServiceConnection conn,
            Context context, Handler activityThread, int flags) {
        mIServiceConnection = new InnerConnection(this);
        mConnection = conn;
        mContext = context;
        mActivityThread = activityThread;
        mLocation = new ServiceConnectionLeaked(null);
        mLocation.fillInStackTrace();
        mFlags = flags;
    }
```

After reading around, I'm suspecting it may be a memory problem but I'm not too sure. When on memory, it was usually ~22mb allocated and ~1mb free.

Comment: This isnt the crash. check your log again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the reason for not declaring your(one of your activity) activity.xml corresponding class in manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".ValidatorDemo">
    </activity>




public class Validatordemo extends Activity{
     .....
}
```